# How can i create a download view in django

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to download a file in **Django**.
My **views.py** is

```
def download_file(request):
  #fill these variables with real values
  fl_path = '/file/path'
  filename = 'downloaded_file_name.extension'
  fl = open(fl_path, 'r')
  mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(fl_path)
  response = HttpResponse(fl, content_type=mime_type)
  response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
  return response
```

Comment: i am trying to create a download view in django but i am out of options.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.http import FileResponse

def download(request, title, isbn):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, title=title, isbn=isbn).file.path
    response = FileResponse(open(book, 'rb'), as_attachment=True)
    return response
```

Comment: i think i figured out a way to do it.